# Echarts change color for type: pie

Tags: colors, pie-chart, echarts

I use this kind of chart - https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link
If I add to the first item for series color red (line:22), so the code looks like:

{
type: 'line',
color: 'red',
smooth: true,
seriesLayoutBy: 'row',
emphasis: { focus: 'series' }
},

It changes the color only in the chart but not in the pie, thank you for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the global color palette instead of changing colors for each series.

[Here is an example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=dataset-link&code=M4UwLgKglgtiD2BXMAKAZogdgYzFemABCgJSEDeAUIYfAA54GEC8F1NhANiAOYiYATAFwUAvgBp2NMPHic8dEVQ4cwAJyg8-akQHIAhgA8owXZJU1gAC3gB3AMIEw_MCLT7OoKYQneV2OXgdQgBtb10AYmwAJgBmAFZYgEYzcIjotAAWePjM1JVIgDYk_QAGfQAOfI5IgUyK6ML46ppIgE4k7AB2fRAWwkiuzLa0Ctj-yOxKwujoiYiAIwF9aLb9ecKQLtKh-dym7fnsTOxsAXH2AF1zDmWwfVBXNgtCYCQ1bBARMJeaEN06Gp4AJELgzANoqUknNxBCoeNYbpIUk8ojkc00VDCuCkVCurprn4OP8ALJQTgAa0IEBA61h8UKADp4rCGoykqyKoyurDtuz6bFGZlWfF2YTfqFdCT9GBsFZ9IQADIy5zg-JJfmEdVC-mijlawWxXmCiqwwpcrri37_exWEAgUCERwBOmETKlTUzRnRM1tZmw2JM4Vu0U-wixaLMq0vf4AdQ8mGQhAAQkDbJgoH1YdFQwGuprMhqw0lTeHBW1YcMxUTLt5fCpDABBYzAJSEMAATzoXwGU2cPCCHd0PhuNA7zZMbZ4GgEAElBCBDCJSiPvNOoMIKO36HocgBSYf1jigDQO75E5S_TvdvScKCYLNEywwWRgKwidSIECjiwnzPAZUOyQMBkw7PQ036FQQBgOh5WASctzQeBsEQVsBj_B1DyJI8VEvF5rx7XQ7wfSDjxfeA3w_NQvx_FQMIA_QgOQUDwLsUiaGg2CHgQ8hCCQlC0N0eisJeHCODwiwCNve9HwlYByMo9tqO_J9XhAU8GKYkCwIGCDaI4Ti4J4vjkNQvRhJ8bD9IklQpIGYjZN-eTX3fJSaNU-jAOAljdLY_SOJgoy0N4_izPQ9T_xEiwxJoGzVC7Qi6EzdjCA3PQkscl41H0AQoDC3RYlKA9_MIT5MGcYJ_niIqcRzA9owsQzuOC1SaFCwTQE4NBdFUmKOE4fQFhATglFaky1BgFV1L0cgFlEJQAAFkWiURiHIARRD3EgeolPqOJwYEezilQoGcGAADl9DgdKgRBMESpoAA3Dwvz0ZaUukWR5CgRQ4WhHbflEbDvFrGhRAAbnYGAO1tfQ1DARkCBQXREDoO4QAnYAAAV4HvCrwQwHBGCIFAQEelwyAkgJMGAMBCCbFt5yQlhCDJlxGSMB0mfgEJSkuSGTrQYgGZMbnKaJanacIXK4Bp_AiFYEXgG5xlns4L9CAAakIJIBYsaHYfhxlHgAeQYeWUGOtSNNGiUaDSgYMo-rhBuG227baoJJrACqZrmxb_i16XYH4eCmG1glVstjatoB3aHtZg6BCOsanpensZdD-WE8-uQFBETO5YIMagd27CSD1sH2FECuoZh-UjdN82kfoYna5r8GgA) based on the one you gave.

```js
option = {
  ...
  //Set the global color palette
  color: ['#c23531','#2f4554','#61a0a8','#d48265','#91c7ae',
  '#749f83','#ca8622','#bda29a','#6e7074','#546570','#c4ccd3'],
  series : [ 
    ...
  ]
}
```